# Cannot get IIS7 to work with my MVC Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

Okay I've read the other StackOverflow postings, forum posts on MSDN, everywhere. I CANNOT get this to work for the life of me.

Here is what I have setup.

In IIS7.0
- Default Site in ASP.NET v4.0 App Pool
- C:\Inetpub\wwwroot as the physical path

I published my MVC2 site in VS2010 to the Default Site path, it succeeded.

Here are the settings for that:
- Same App Pool
- C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PerfectSchedule as the physical path
- Default Document is Views/Home.mvc

I open the URL in my IE browser
- http://localhost/ --> just gives me the Apache "It works!" page
- http://localhost/PerfectSchedule --> The WebPage cannot be found
- http://perfectschedule/ --> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apache "It works!"

And this is IIS7 you say? Looks like a **BIG** clue. Perhaps you have Apache running on port 80? Try killing Apache and restarting W3SVC.

Comment: I actually knew this sorry. I was using http://localhost:8080/ but it still wasn't working. I figured it out though. THANKS!